# Masking a UIView

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, mask

I use the following code all the time in my view controller:

```
UIView *view = [[CustomView alloc] init];
UIView *mask = [[CustomMask alloc] init];
[view layer].mask =[mask layer];
```

and it masks the view as I want.

However, when it is not in a view controller I get the error:

'Request for member 'mask' in something not a structure or a union'

E.g. I want to apply the mask in the CustomView class itself. So I would have:

```
UIView *mask = [[CustomMask alloc] init];
[self layer].mask =[mask layer];
```

This produces the error. If I do it in my AppDelegate class with two images I get the same error again.

Can anyone explain how I can get the result I want.

Many thanks

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. _Exactly_ what I needed. You have answered my question in your question, that is: **How to mask a UIView with another UIView (without using an image)?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

needed to be added.